# How to make a TextBox read-only based on the item selected in the ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, textbox

I would be so greatful if you could help meee, thx!

HERE IS THE XAML

```
<ComboBox Margin="8" Name="cmbox" SelectionChanged="cmbox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">ESCALONADO</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>INTEGRAL</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding Testcmb}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8"/>
```

HERE IS A LITTLE BIT OF THE CODE BEHIND

I tried to attribute the value of the property Testcmb based on the selected item on the combobox, and then make the bindin to the textbox to turn it as a IsReadOnly="true". Is the sintax right?

```
private void cmbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbox.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        (Object).Testcmb = true;
    }
    else
    {
        (Object).Testcmb = false;
    }
}

private bool _testcmb;     
public bool Testcmb
{   
    get { return _testcmb; }
    set
    {
        if (this._testcmb != value)
        {
            this._testcmb = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Testcmb");
        };
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you use type casting for your property? `(Object).Testcmb = true;`? `Testcmb = true` should be enough. And what is the result if you run the app? Syntax error or wrong work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Your syntax is indeed correct, however you are mixing data binding with event handlers and all of this within view's code-behind.

You can do what you want using `Style` which is more clear for this kind of UI logic, as for me. Here is XAML-only solution:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbox">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="ESCALONADO"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="INTEGRAL" />
</ComboBox>
<TextBox Text="Some text...">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=cbox}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```